# Typescript Literal Object from Tuple where Keys and Values are the Same

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to create a helper function that simplifies creating lookups.

So given this:

```
const obj = produceLiteral([`foo`, `bar`, `foo`, `moo`]);
```

`obj` should be typed as:

```
interface Obj {
  foo: `foo`;
  bar: `bar`;
  moo: `moo`;
}
```

Not sure how.

Comment: How can that simplify lookups ?

Comment: I like to create ids such that I can do `myIds.foo` this will return `foo`. This is typesafe and non-magic thus can be shared around the codebase

Comment: Will the values in the array be known at compile time ? or it's only known at runtime ?

Comment: Known at compile time (tuple)

Comment: There's nothing more type safe or less magic about this than just using the string literals directly. In fact, using them directly is even less to type. Type safety comes from whatever is accepting these values to be typed correctly, so having a union type of the possible literal values should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a tuple `['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'moo']`, here is one way to derive the needed interface:

```
const tuple = [`foo`, `bar`, `foo`, `moo`] as const

type Obj = { [K in typeof tuple[number]]: K }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=46&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUxgXhgbQAYDMQRcAaGXAIwEMAnU8w4s3AWyNwF0YqIZRIoAKEFQAnonQB5CgCtMMAN44A0jACWYOONQh8cJGmxh4LCqhocOALhiqAvsKA)

To create the actual object:

```
const tuple = [`foo`, `bar`, `foo`, `moo`] as const

type Obj = { [K in typeof tuple[number]]: K }

const obj = tuple.reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, [val]: val }), {}) as Obj
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=76&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUxgXhgbQAYDMQRcAaGXAIwEMAnU8w4s3AWyNwF0YqIZRIoAKEFQAnonQB5CgCtMMAN44A0jACWYOONQh8cJGmxh4LCqhocOALhiqAvsP7QYIWfIQpUAOhqoAJvDAqAAUwVTAwGQAblTIAJSYAHwwwUpe6eGRODHI1jA5MHZxZApF3LzSMsJAA)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to "lukejohn" on the Fenders Slack for this answer:

```
function produceLiteral<Key extends string>(keys: Key[]): {[key in Key]: key} {
    const literal: Partial<{[key in Key]: key}> = {}

    for (const key of keys) {
        literal[key] = key
    }

    return literal as {[key in Key]: key}
}

const obj = produceLiteral([`foo`, `bar`, `foo`, `moo`]);
```

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wCYggUwDIxQ6oCGANgDwDSOAnojgB5FgYDOibUqMYA5gD4AFAGs6bAFyIatANoBdAJRSA3rLH1e0uvKkaAvohUAoRGcQQEXRGULFyUgAolUschTUbEWmbsQGBRABeI31jU3NgOFREIUsway84YH9xRSMI83NbIlIydR1g1NpMxDDS1BwoEFQkHPsyRBIOTzpvJF89OjDy+Os4ACMAKyK0TGx8OzyhWQADKLhZgBpEWYGXZdWFzdmAWzhFpQBuYyA

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, but I think what you are looking for is:

```
const produceLiteral = (input: string[]): Obj => input.reduce((acc, curr) => ({...acc, [curr]: curr} as Obj), {})
```

But maybe typing will become a problem if the input array changes, I am not completly sure but maybe a more generic interface like

```
interface Obj {
   [key: string]: string
}
```

Comment: No I want TS to infer input and generate Obj type for me